# Object detection running very slowly on laptop

Tags: tensorflow

I stepped through the following tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md

I then tried to run inference using: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

This ran very quickly (in ~1s for each image). I noticed that the code is pulling down a pre-trained model (not the one I tried in the first tutorial) from http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17.

When I load and perform inference using the graph that I exported in the tutorial, it takes around 10s to finish. I exported the graph using:

```
python object_detection/export_inference_graph.py \
    --input_type image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix model.ckpt-${CHECKPOINT_NUMBER} \
    --output_directory exported_graphs
```

I'm running inference using this code:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'exported_graphs', 'saved_model'))
model = model.signatures['serving_default']

output_dict = model(input_tensor)
```

I'm running a MacOS with HighSierra. Have I exported the graph in a sub-optimal way? Is my machine just not fast enough? I'm still very much a beginner so any direction would be really helpful - I might be missing something really basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph which you run first was of `ssd_mobilenet_v1` which took you around 1 sec. The other graph if of `faster_rcnn_resnet101` which took you around 10 sec. The two of them are completely different architecture. `faster_rcnn_resnet101` will run slower than `ssd_mobilenet_v1`.

Comment: Could I use a GPU for inference? Or is that just during training?

Comment: yes you can use GPU for both inference and training.

Comment: What would be the most cost-effective provider to use if I wanted to use a GPU during inference for my application? It seems like I shouldn't need to pay $100+ per month if I'm running inference a few times per day, no? (Accepted your answer)

Comment: on aws there are options for GPU inferencing. There is also an option for paying according to usage. Just check aws website.